Transformation w/ Rolling Regression (Residual Function)
In a time series with OLS regression curve $\widehat Y$ (rolling linear regression), and with $n=20,$ what can I say about this transformation? This formula is similar to a differential minus its integral. This is an error function (residual) minus its (crudely scaled?) summation.
$$
(Y_n-\widehat Y_n) - \left[ \frac14 \sum_{i=1}^n \left(Y_i - \widehat Y_i \right) \right]
$$
The first term is the $n$-th residual of the OLS model. The second term is closely related to the SSE or MSE functions.  However, I have summed the raw residuals without squaring so this is basically a term that follows the trend in the residuals.

What is the variance of each term?  (1)
Can I use SSE or MSE to find (1)?
Does anybody recognize this kind of data transform? Related literature or topics? (3)

P.S.
The "$1/4$" in the second term is really just $5/n$ for my formula.  Note: For me this is a really strange problem because the model is being recalculated for each $20$-period subinterval. This formula is used to analyze momentum in financial assets.

Until you explain how the $\hat Y_i$ are found, your first two questions are not answerable.  Note, too--for purposes of searching and communication--that this would not ordinarily be considered a data transformation.  It's evidently an algorithm to adjust a residual--perhaps for bias reduction, perhaps for forecasting, maybe something else.  But what exactly it's doing, and why, cannot be determined without knowing the details.  Re your edit: why do you replace "$5/n$" with "$1/4$"?? That's a fundamental change, even though for $n=20$ the values of those quantities agree.

Its ordinary least squares (linear in one variable!) applied to each n = 20 minutes subset of the data.  Each 20 period subset of the data (call it X) has a unique Y-hat_i  for that period.  The regression  curve is formed by joining each linear segment into a continuous curve.

I don't follow what you mean by "unique $\hat Y_i$ for that period."  If so, then what is the role of the subscript $i$?  And by "applied to each ... subset of the data," it's unclear whether you are performing separate regressions in each subset.  Could you perhaps offer a simple illustration of what you're doing, perhaps with a smaller $n$ for simplicity?

Sure.  Let's say I have 1 hour of data.  That is 60 minutes so there will be a unique ols reg line for the data set [x1,x20], the data in [x2,x21], the data in [x3,x22] and so on.

All the information I have is from these links.
https://toslc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/Tech-Indicators/studies-library/R-S/RelativeVolatilityIndex and it referenced https://toslc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/Tech-Indicators/studies-library/R-S/RelativeStrength as well.

This is the description of the predictor function.https://toslc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/Tech-Indicators/studies-library/G-L/Inertia <<

Thanks -- but I can't find any useful information in those links.  Where did you locate the formula you quote?
